# Remove EventListener and resume video play

Tags: javascript

I have a video which I pause with javascript by adding addEventListener.

```
    <video id="home-hero-video" preload autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted">
       <source src="videourl.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

The video is on autoplay and when the video reach the 5s it pause.

```
var video = document.getElementById('home-hero-video');
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
    if (this.currentTime >= 5.000) {
        this.pause();
    }
}, false);
```

What I want is on scroll down the video to start/resume playing again from the 5s to the end.

```
   var scrollableElement = document.body;

    scrollableElement.addEventListener('wheel', checkScrollDirection);

    function checkScrollDirection(event) {
        if (checkScrollDirectionIsUp(event)) {
            // console.log('scroll UP');
        } else {
           video.removeEventListener("timeupdate");
           video.play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the HTML code?

Comment: What is the question? I think you need to let us know what you want to achieve.

Comment: What I want to achieve is on scroll down to remove the EventListener and resume/play video again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to detect what direction the user is scrolling, we need to:

- define a counter outside of any function (`start`)

  ```
  let start = 0;
  ```
- bind the `window` object to the `scroll` event

  ```
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {//...
  ```
- next, get the distance between the top of viewport and the top of the `<body>` (`stop`)

  ```
  const bcr = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
  const stop = bcr.top;
  ```
- and when the scroll event fires, compare the the values of `start` and `stop`. If `start` is greater than `stop` then user is scrolling down.

  ```
  if (stop < start) {//...
  ```
- when that condition is met, unbind the video from the `timeupdate` event and resume `.play()`

  ```
  video.play();
  video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', first5Sec);
  ```

**Note** the only way to remove an event listener is have both `.addEventListener()` and `.removeEventListener()` match in the element they are bound to and the parameters:

```js
DOMObject.addEventListener(event, eventHandler, capture)
DOMObject.removeEventListener(event, eventHandler, capture)
// The only difference between them is ".add" and ".remove"
```

***Details are commented in example***

***Do not do anything until the video is paused, then scroll down***

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", first5Sec);

function first5Sec(e) {
  if (this.currentTime >= 5.000) {
    this.pause();
  }
}
// Define counter outside of function
let start = 0;

// Bind window to the scroll event
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  // Reference the BCR of <body>
  const bcr = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
  /*
  Get the distance from the top of viewport and the top of the body
  */
  const stop = bcr.top;
  /*
  If that distance is less than start, resume video
  */
  if (stop < start) {
    video.play();
    /*
    Unbind video from 'timeupdate' event Both .addEventListener() and
    .removeEventListener() must be identical in parameters
    */
    video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', first5Sec);
  }
  // Set start as stop for the next scroll
  start = stop;
});
```

```css
:root {
  font: 300 62.5%/1 'Segoe UI';
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 200vh;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

figure {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30%;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <figure>
      <video src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs12s3.mp4" preload autoplay muted></video>
    </figure>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly.

I appreciate the detailed explanation of the code. It's simple and easy to understand.